# After I did a system update and rebooted, it didn't boot

Tags: boot, updates, system

I did auto system update and installed it. After reboot, my system didn't boot up and showed this error:

> Dev loop0: unable to read RDB block 8

Comment: What is the version of Ubuntu _before_ and your aspired version _after_ the update?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/710035/dev-loop0-unable-to-read-rdb-block-8

Comment: How are we to know?  We don't yet know what Ubuntu product, or release of that product you're using is.  You may perform upgrades daily, weekly or monthly, and especially given we don't know what product/release we can't look up what upgrades may be related. You've provided too little detail except for *wild guesses*